# gvim - Highlight cursor and cursor line differently

Tags: vim, colors, gvim

Using [happy hacking](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/happy_hacking.vim), I can't tell where my cursor is in a file with only one line. Usually the column highlighter would allow me to see it.

How can I make the cursor field highlight look different from the cursor line?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the color scheme file in `~/.vim/colors/`. Look for `CursorLine`.

There might be a link between `CursorLine` and `Cursor`, which you will want to comment out using `"` at the start of the line:

```
hi! link CursorLine   Cursor
```

You will then probably want to define `CursorLine` in a way different from how `Cursor` is defined. For example like this:

```
call s:Color("Cursor",     "NONE",   s:gray2,   "NONE",     s:t_gray2)
call s:Color("CursorLine", "NONE",   s:black2,  "NONE",     s:t_gray2)
```

This is assuming these colors are defined. For examples, please search for `s:gray2` in [happy_hacking.vim](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/happy_hacking.vim/blob/master/colors/happy_hacking.vim).